# Is there a way to persist messages when the broker is offline?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

is there a way to support a scenario where broker is offline so that messages can be stored temporarily in disc and attempt to submit once the broker comes online. This is to provide resilience in scenarios where the broker goes down. I have not found anything in the documentation yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything like this built into MassTransit. If the broker is unavailable, messages cannot be published or sent.

Comment: Thanks Chris for taking the time to answer. It might be useful to have some kind of offline support for disconnected scenarios. I was looking at the message audit feature in Mass Transit which could be used. The idea is to persist messages to disc when disconnected and publish once connection is restored.
https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/audit.html#metadata-factory

Comment: Oh, I understand the request, it just isn't something I plan on implementing.

Comment: What is the alternate way that MT guarantee the delivery of the message? I know only that Message Store such as this: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/GuaranteedMessaging.html that the message is saved in store persistently with the entities saved state in the same transaction. CAP do something like this. How Mass Transit deals with Guaranteed Messaging Deliveries? Does only Saga Persistent State Machine is the only way of the Guarantees?

Comment: MassTransit uses the message broker for storage, if it isn't available, you can't send/publish messages.